Shrink border of a HTML element which shares space with a floating element
When a floating element takes up some space, the "normal" text makes room to accommodate the floating element. But the border around the normal text does not and instead intersects with the floating element.
In the example below, how can I make the first red box end before the blue box starts with some gap, and not overlap? And let the second red box, which does not need to share space with the floating element, still take up 100%?


div#toc {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div.warn {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div id="toc">
  <h2>Table of contents</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
  <p>In the beginning ...</p>
  <div class="warn">
    Fairy tale, watch out!
  </div>
  <p>... and were married happily ever after.</p>
  <div class="warn">
    Don't retell!
  </div>
</div>




The first question would be "why?", because the text inside that div is going to do exactly what it should do (wrapping as needed to accommodate the floating element).

Why? Because I want the "warn" box to have a red border.

What else does it need to do though? Does it need to be 100% width of "whatever space there is" or can it be a normal inline text block?

I don't think I understand the question. If there is a background, it should also shrink to the available space. If there are other elements like imgs they probably also should shrink although I don't have that need right now. My primary need is regular text with a border.

It sounds like what you want is one of those things that the standard CSS box model can't do. You could have a look at CSS grid, and specifically its masonry layout, but that's still experimental, so you may just have to reach for a JS solution here (there are a number of libraries for that, using the same "masonry" term). Unless, of course, this is for specific content you've already written and you just want it to look good. In that case: nothing wrong with just tailoring the CSS to that specific content.

Block-level boxes that establish an independent formatting context shrink to avoid floats. The most direct way to make a box establish a block formatting context (the most suitable type of independent formatting context in this case) is to give it display: flow-root.
Use margin on the float to create the gap.


div#toc {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div.warn {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flow-root;
}
<div id="toc">
  <h2>Table of contents</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
  <p>In the beginning ...</p>
  <div class="warn">
    Fairy tale, watch out!
  </div>
  <p>... and were married happily ever after.</p>
  <div class="warn">
    Don't retell!
  </div>
</div>




There's always one more CSS keyword I've never heard of! And it does it!!
